# What is "site specific" data?

Tags: python, fhs

I have heard references in the FHS to "site-specific" data. Python also has the notion of "site packages".

In FHS, is "site" just a general term for an instance of someone using an FHS filesystem? IE, my computer would be a "site". A computer lab with lots of computers connected using NFS would be a "site", etc?

Answer (score 2):

"Site-specific" data in FHS and "site packages" in Python are two different things.

#### FHS: site-specific data

As it states in [documentation](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM):

> /srv : Data for services provided by this system
>
> This main purpose of specifying this is so that users may find the location of the data files for particular service, and so that services which require a single tree for readonly data, writable data and scripts (such as cgi scripts) can be reasonably placed. Data that is only of interest to a specific user should go in that users' home directory.
>
> The methodology used to name subdirectories of /srv is unspecified as there is currently no consensus on how this should be done. One method for structuring data under /srv is by protocol, eg. ftp, rsync, www, and cvs. On large systems it can be useful to structure /srv by administrative context, such as /srv/physics/www, /srv/compsci/cvs, etc. This setup will differ from host to host. Therefore, no program should rely on a specific subdirectory structure of /srv existing or data necessarily being stored in /srv. However /srv should always exist on FHS compliant systems and should be used as the default location for such data.

So here you can put data files for a particular service, such as FTP, WWW, or CVS (in contrast data that only pertains to a specific user placed in the /home/ directory).

#### Python: site packages

Here it's just a location where 3rd party Python packages (not part of core Python distribution) are installed. E.g. for Python3 in Ubuntu it's:

```
>>> import site; site.getsitepackages();
['/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.4/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/dist-python']
```

#### Update: meaning of 'site' in FHS

By 'site' it means resource that's served to users on different hosts via network. E.g. 'web-site' is a set of web-pages served via http, or if you want to give other users access to your git-repository and running git daemon so they can connect to it via git/ssh protocols.